# Storing a printed line into a String?

Tags: java

I'd like to know if there is any way to store a series of texts which are printed using System.out.print into a specific String so that it can be used to recall the line in the future.

For example :

```
String oldLine=null;
int x = 4;
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
int result = x+i;
System.out.print(result+"\t"); }
```

The result would be then something like:

```
4   5  6  7  9  10 ....
```

Now I'd like to know if I can store this line into:

```
String oldLine;
```

So whenever I print oldLine I can print the same line as :

```
4   5  6  7  9  10 ....
```

Comment: Why not just change your code so you don't use `System.out.print`, but instead use a `StringBuilder`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `StringBuilder` for this:

```
String oldLine = null;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder ();
int x = 4;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    int result = x + i;
    sb.append (String.valueOf (result));
    sb.append ('\t');
}

oldLine = sb.toString ();
System.out.println (oldLine);
```

### [Demo](http://ideone.com/bjWt6)

Answer (score 1):

Use a `StringBuilder`.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(String.valueOf(result));
```

And then finally convert your `StringBuilder` to a `String`.

```
oldLine = sb.toString();
```

For further info, read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) and [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html).